# Refilling 2D arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two 2d arrays "a", "b" (empty array) with the same size, I have to change "a" due to a certain function that save it's new values in "b", then I have to change the new values according to the same function, so the program will save b's new values in a and then back to a.
When the arrays are printed only the first two ones are printed!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MSIZE 10

void new_gen(char * a[MSIZE],int s,char** b);      /*the function we talked                     about*/
void print_m(char** b,int s);   /*prints matrix*/
void cpy_m(char** b, char** a, int s);

int main()
{
    int Size, gen, i, j;
    printf("Enter number of generations\t");   
    scanf("%d", &gen);
    printf("\nEnter size of the matrix (max size is %d and min is 2)\t", MSIZE);
    scanf("%d", &Size);
    char **m = (char**) malloc(Size*sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (char*) malloc(Size*sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("Enter matrix of first generation\n");
    for (i=0; i<Size; i++)  {
        for (j=0; j<Size; j++)  {
            scanf(" %c", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }
    print_m(m, Size);

    for (i=1; i<gen; i++)
    {
        char **n = (char**) malloc(Size*sizeof(char*));
        for (i=0; i<Size; i++)
        {
            n[i] = (char*) malloc(Size*sizeof(char));
        }
        new_gen(m, Size, n);
        print_m(n, Size);
        cpy_m(n, m, Size);

    }
    return 0;   }


void print_m(char** b, int s)
{
    int i, j;
    putchar('\n');
    for (i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<s; j++)    {
            printf("%c", *(*(b+i)+j));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return;
}


void cpy_m(char* b[MSIZE],char** a, int s)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<s; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<s; j++) {
            *(*(a+i)+j) = b[i][j];
        }
    return;
}}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? I see your general problem statement, and I see your code. What specifically do you want to know? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this pair of nested loops

```
for (i=1; i<gen; i++)
{
    char **n = (char**) malloc(Size*sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        n[i] = (char*) malloc(Size*sizeof(char));
    }
    new_gen(m, Size, n);
    print_m(n, Size);
    cpy_m(n, m, Size);
}
```

First point, both the loops use `i` as the control variable, but they are nested.

Second point, you overwrite the pointers from `malloc` in each iteration (there is no `free`).